# Can't Install Elementary OS Hera on Dell Precision 3541

Tags: system-installation, uefi, dell

Dell Precision 3541 machine came with Ubuntu preloaded.  Can not get Elementary OS to boot in UEFI mode.  Looks like it loading from USB. Elementary OS logo pops up and says "Try or install elementary OS" at bottom it says "enter: boot `e' options`c' command line".

Enter and Elementary OS logo reappears for a moment.  The looks like Ubuntu takes over shows a window with Dell logo that says "This Dell Recovery Media can be use to restore the original factory software.  It is recommended you back up all important data before running this too.  ERROR: This recovery media only functions on Dell and alientware systems purchased with Ubuntu"

C takes me to grub command line.

E takes me to a terminal looking screen titled "GNU GRUB VERSION 2.02"

Boot Sequence: From USB
UEFI Boot Path Security: None
USB Configuration: Enable USB Boot Support and Enable External USB Port both checked.
Secure Boot: Secure Boot Enable not checked.
Secure Boot Mode: Audit Mode
SATA Operation: AHCI
No options for legacy boot found anywhere.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up returning the device to Dell and ordering an Oryx Pro from System76 which is rated online as a Elementary OS friendly device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with precision 5530 with Ubuntu1604 preinstalled.
My workaround was to create backup of OS recovery partition and format it. After that Elementary OS installation started correctly.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately I've already returned the machine to Dell.

Answer (score 0):

I have a OptiPlex 7050, and I have the same problem.
I just opened another question about it (I searched a lot and didn't find yours), but I don't want to erase the recovery partition.

I created a Ubuntu Install USB and it boots perfectly. ElementaryOS does not.

Has anybody found out a solution for this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please only post answers in the answer section. Thanks.